# JavaFX "move" nodes

Tags: java, javafx

I'am new new to JavaFX, and I got a problem. I'm trying to move Nodes with UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT, if I just move my "Player" node, it's work perfectly, but I wanna make a game like sokoban, so my Player node can move "Crate" node, the problem is if I press the RIGHT next to the Crate, it swap the places, but not working correctly here is the moving method :

```
private void lepes(int i, int j, int target_i, int target_j){
      int ai, aj;
      int bi, bj;

      ai = i;
      aj = j;

      bi = target_i;
      bj = target_j;

      MyNode nodeA = playfield[ai][aj];
      nodeA.toFront();

      MyNode nodeB = playfield[bi][bj];
      nodeB.toFront();

      playfield[ai][aj] = nodeB;
      playfield[bi][bj] = nodeA;

      Path pathA = new Path();
      pathA.getElements().add (new MoveTo ( nodeA.getTranslateX() + nodeA.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0, nodeA.getTranslateY() + nodeA.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));
      pathA.getElements().add (new LineTo( nodeB.getTranslateX() + nodeB.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0, nodeB.getTranslateY() + nodeB.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));


      PathTransition pathTransitionA = new PathTransition(); 
      pathTransitionA.setDuration(Duration.millis(1));
      pathTransitionA.setNode( nodeA);
      pathTransitionA.setPath(pathA);

      pathTransitionA.play();

      Path pathB = new Path();
      pathB.getElements().add (new MoveTo ( nodeB.getTranslateX() + nodeB.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0, nodeB.getTranslateY() + nodeB.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));
      pathB.getElements().add (new LineTo( nodeA.getTranslateX() + nodeA.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2.0, nodeA.getTranslateY() + nodeA.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2.0));

      PathTransition pathTransitionB = new PathTransition(); 
      pathTransitionB.setDuration(Duration.millis(1));
      pathTransitionB.setNode( nodeB);
      pathTransitionB.setPath(pathB);

      pathTransitionB.play();


      pathTransitionA.setOnFinished( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

          @Override
          public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

              if( (pathTransitionB.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING))
                  return;
          }
      });

       pathTransitionB.setOnFinished( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

          @Override
          public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

              if( (pathTransitionA.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING))
                  return;
          }
      });


}
```

and here is the eventHandler

```
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
          @Override
          public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getCode()==KeyCode.RIGHT) { 

                if(jatekosX < 8 && playfield[jatekosX+1][jatekosY].getHisNumber() == 2){
                    lepes(jatekosX, jatekosY, jatekosX+1, jatekosY);
                    jatekosX++;
                    lepesek++;
                }
                else if(jatekosX < 8 && playfield[jatekosX+1][jatekosY].getHisNumber() == 1 ){

                    lepes(jatekosX+1, jatekosY, jatekosX+2, jatekosY);          
                    lepes(jatekosX, jatekosY, jatekosX+1, jatekosY);
                    jatekosX++;
                    lepesek++; 

                }

                System.out.println("Jobbra");
                System.out.println("X: " + jatekosX + "Y: " + jatekosY + " lépés: " + lepesek + "\n");
            } 
          }       
        });
```

Here is the picture next to crate node, https://postimg.org/image/7qkqxnxs5/

And here is after a Right step, https://postimg.org/image/t1ib1xfwl/

I Don't know what causes this.

Comment: So it's time to learn how to debug code

Comment: if(man is intersecting crate from left and right arrow is pressed){move crate right and move man right}

Comment: I think this would work better with animation timer.